# nginx return image for a specific endpoint

Tags: nginx

I want to return a custom favicon from nginx, so I added the following:

```
location ~ ^/favicon.ico {
    expires 2w;
    access_log off;
    try_files $uri /path/to/custom/ico.ico;
}
```

but when I do `curl foo.com/favicon.ico` I get a 404. How come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    expires 2w;
    access_log off;
    alias /path/to/custom/ico.ico;
}
```

I put the `=` because `using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates`. So it might be slightly faster.

Comment: What if somebody does `foo.com/favicon.ico?bar=true`?

Comment: `nginx` `location`s ignore query strings